# Getting the end-memory address of a memory-range via python / ctypes

Tags: python, unit-testing, ctypes, python-2.5

I'm creating a very basic (coverage) unittest for a (hardware) C-interface in python.

A function of that C-interface needs memory-addresses since it talks directly to memory.

The prototype of the function is:

```
void function( ulong startAddress, ulong endAddress, ulong curAddress, nofPaddingElements )
```

The startAddress, endAddress and curAddress are basically memory-addresses of an array-of-structs.

On the web (and stackoverflow ;-) ) I found references that if I want to do something with ctypes, so that is what I use.

For the startAddress and curAddress one can follow http://starship.python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/tutorial.html#arrays and http://starship.python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/tutorial.html#pointers to obtain a pointer to the address of the first entry and a pointer to the address of the current entry.

But the endAddress is the problem.
It is the real end address of the memory area which needs to be allocated by the function.
So for an array of ints of 10 long it would mean the 'address of i[10]' if you get what I mean (Pratically one can of course only use i[0] till i[9], but I mean with i[10] the address where the 10th entry ends / the 11th entry would start ==> the end-address of the array).

Does anybody know how I can obtain this end-address via python / ctypes?

(Refactoring the C-code so it does not need the end-address, is not an option, it is already working correctly for years, it only did not have an unittest)

Oh btw. the software-release I'm currently working with is using python 2.5 (later releases use python 2.7, but it first needs to be developed on this release)

Comment: If you know the size and number of your structs you should be able to calculate it relatively easily. `ctypes.sizeof()` returns the size of say a struct.

Comment: I assume `ulong` is `unsigned long`, but a `long` isn't always big enough to hold a pointer (e.g. it's always 4 bytes in Windows). Use `intptr_t` for the addresses in the C function.

Comment: @eryksun: Since it is stable working code I'm not allowed to change the interface. 

I'm working on Solaris (and it will be ported to Linux) and according to the web the length of long is 8 bytes for both on the versions used by the company I'm programming for. Thus it will hold a pointer. Thanx anyway for your comment

Comment: Still, you can define these parameters as pointers in ctypes, such as `function.argtypes = (c_void_p, c_void_p, c_void_p, c_ulong)`. Then you can use `byref` to write code that's closer to using `&` in C. For example: `function(i, byref(i, sizeof(i._type_) * 10), byref(i, sizeof(i._type_) * k), npad)`. Note the first argument doesn't need `byref` because arrays are passed as pointers, but you can use `byref(i)` if you want. The second argument uses the optional offset parameter.

Comment: You can simplify that a bit if the array element is a non-simple type (e.g. a `Structure`, `Array`, or `_Pointer` instance). In this case indexing the array returns a ctypes data type that can be passed to `byref`. For example: `function(i, byref(i[9], sizeof(i[0])), byref(i[k]), npad)`.