# sanity-check: Am I using ctypes in the correct way?

Tags: python, unit-testing, ctypes, python-2.5

This is a follow-up of [Getting the end-memory address of a memory-range via python / ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29495767/getting-the-end-memory-address-of-a-memory-range-via-python-ctypes)

I'm finally that far that I can start my testing, but I'm not sure if I'm doing things right, since the addresses are of addresses within lists of structs containing structs. And in C are calculated using macros.

I think I did it correctly, but I'm uncertain about if I set the argtypes correctly. And thus would like your opinion.

Note: the target-function under test has the following foot-print:

```
void function( ulong startAddress, ulong endAddress, ulong curAddress, int nofPaddingElements )
```

Note2: I have to test this against real hardware, therefore I did not implement to many shortcuts at this moment.

I'm not allowed to post real code here, so I will give pseudo code as far as possible.

1) the type-definition of the buffer-struct. Contains pointers to other structs, but not as pointer, but as ulongs.

```
class My_Buffer_t( ctypes.Structure ):
    _fields_ = [
       ( "some_bool" , ctypes.c_bool ),
       ( "head",       ctypes.c_ulong ),
       ( "tail",       ctypes.c_ulong ),
       ( "headSize",   ctypes.c_ulong ),
       ( "dataSize",   ctypes.c_ulong ) ]
```

Main data-struct, exists out of 2 other structs

```
class Struct1( ctypes.Structure ):
    _fields_ = [
       ( "entry1", Struct2 ),
       ( "entry2", Struct3 ) ]

class Struct2( ctypes.Structure ):
# Only contains basic types
    _fields_ = [
       ( "data1", ctypes.c_int ),
       ...
       ( "datax", cyptes.c_ushort ) ]

class Struct3( ctypes.Structure ):
# Mix of basic types and 1 other structure
    _fields_ = [
       ( "data1", ctypes.c_double ),
       ...
       ( "datax", cyptes.c_int ),

       ( "timestamp_data1", TimeStampStruct ),
       ...
       ( "timestamp_datax", TimeStampStruct ) ]

class TimeStampStruct( ctypes.Structure ):
    _fields_ = [
       ( "field1", ctypes.c_ulong ),
       ( "field2", ctypes.c_ulong ) ]
```

List creation-function (I basically copied the C-function):

```
def create_list( bufsize, buffer ):
    # buffer is of type My_Buffer_t

    # It actually creates some shared memory where headSize also needed to be divided by 
    # ctypes.sizeof( ctypes.c_size_t )
    # And afterwards again was multiplied by ctypes.sizeof( ctypes.c_size_t )
    # But since the shared-memory is not of importance for the function-under test I left
    # that part out.
    headSize = (ctypes.c_size_t )( ( ctypes.sizeof(
            My_Buffer_t ) + ctypes.sizeof( ctypes.c_size_t ) - 1 ) )
    dataSize = ( ctypes.c_size_t ) ( ( bufsize + ctypes.sizeof(
            ctypes.c_size_t ) - 1 ) / ctypes.sizeof( ctypes.c_size_t ) )

    buffer.some_bool = True
    buffer.head      = 0
    buffer.tail      = 0
    buffer.headSize  = (ctypes.c_ulong)(headSize)
    buffer.dataSize  = (ctypes.c_ulong)(dataSize)

    return buffer
```

The macro I translated to python function (again I kept as close as possible to the C-code)

```
def get_data_address( list_ptr ):
    # list_ptr is of type My_buffer_t, but the data is of type Struct1
    return( ( ctypes.c_ulong )( ctypes.c_void_p )( ctypes.c_byte )(
            list_ptr ) + ( list_ptr.headSize ) )
```

How it all comes together

```
max_entries = 100000
list_size   = max_entries * ctypes.sizeof( Struct1 )

# First argtype use:
create_list.argtypes = ( ctypes.c_ulong, My_Buffer_t )
list_ptr             = create_list( list_size, My_Buffer_t() )

# Determine the addresses (2nd use of argtypes):
get_data_address.argtypes = ( My_Buffer_t )
startAddress              = get_data_address( list_ptr )
endAddress                = startAddress + list_size
curAddress                = startAddress
nofPaddingElements        = ctypes.sizeof( struct3 ) / ctypes.sizeof( ctypes.c_int )

# Call the SUT (final use of argtypes)
function.argtypes = ( ctypes.c_ulong, ctypes.c_ulong, ctypes.c_ulong, ctypes.c_int )
function( startAddress, endAddress, curAddress, nofPaddingElements )

# rest of the test is simple basic python
```

Am I doing things wrong here or maybe over-complicated? Or am I doing it correct?

Comment: If `create_list` is a C function, why do you have a Python implementation? Are you sure it wants the `My_Buffer_t` struct passed by value instead of by reference?  How does `list_ptr` relate to the passed in struct?

Comment: `argtypes` needs to be a sequence, so it's `get_data_address.argtypes = (My_Buffer_t,)`. Note the comma. Also, you're not setting `restype` in either case, so it's using the default `c_int` type, whereas I suppose you want `restype = c_void_p` to avoid truncating pointers.